# How do i send the message to multiple clients in java Client-Server Program

Tags: java, netbeans, client-server

Multiple Clients say(A, B, C, D etc) make connection to one server through same socket. They all send messages to server as and when required. Client messages are sent only to server(and not to other clients). But whenever server sends a message it should be delivered to all the clients. Please help me out jam only able to get server message on only 1 client

//MultithreadedServer.java

```
package server;
import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;
public class MultithreadedServer
{



Vector<ClientHandler> clients = new Vector<ClientHandler>();
    Vector<String> users = new Vector<String>();
    private static ServerSocket servSocket;
    private static final int PORT = 1247;

public MultithreadedServer() throws IOException{
    servSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
  while(true) {

                Socket client = servSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("\nNew client accepted.\n");




    ClientHandler handler;
        handler = new ClientHandler(client);
        clients.add(handler);

}
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    MultithreadedServer ms = new MultithreadedServer();

}
class ClientHandler extends Thread
{

private Socket client;
private BufferedReader in;
private PrintWriter out;
String name,message,response;

public ClientHandler(Socket socket)
{
    //Set up reference to associated socket...
    client = socket;
    try
    {
        in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        client.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(
                    client.getOutputStream(),true);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    start();
}
public void sendMessage(String  msg)  {
        System.out.println("is it even coming here?");
    out.println("Server:" + msg);
}
public void boradcast(String message)  {
    // send message to all connected users
    for (ClientHandler c : clients) {

          c.out.println("Server: hello");
}
}
public String getUserName() {  
        return name; 
    }
 public void run()
  {
    try
    {
        String received;
        do
        {   System.out.println("Enter Your Message: ");
            String msg = in.readLine();
            out.println(msg);
            boradcast("testing");
            received = in.readLine();
            out.println("ECHO: " + received);
        //Repeat above until 'QUIT' sent by client...

        }while (!received.equals("QUIT"));
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (client!=null)
            {
                System.out.println(
                            "Closing down connection...");
                client.close();
                        }
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
   }
}}
//ClientProgram

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*; 
public class Client
 {
private static InetAddress host;
private static final int PORT = 1247;
private static Socket link;
private static BufferedReader in;
private static PrintWriter out;
private static BufferedReader keyboard; 
public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException
{
    try
  {
        host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        link = new Socket(host, PORT);
        in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                            link.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(
                            link.getOutputStream(),true);
        keyboard = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String message, response;
        do
        {
            System.out.print(
                  "Enter message ('QUIT' to exit): ");
            message = keyboard.readLine();
           //Send message to server on
            //the socket's output stream...
            out.println(message);
            //Accept response frm server on
            //the socket's input stream...
            response = in.readLine();
            //Display server's response to user...
            System.out.println(response);
        }while (!message.equals("QUIT"));
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException uhEx)
    {
        System.out.println(
                    "\nHost ID not found!\n");
    }
    catch(IOException ioEx)
    {
        ioEx.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (link!=null)
            {
                System.out.println(
                        "Closing down connection...");
                link.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ioEx)
        {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

An obvious way to do this would be to cycle through all ClientHandlers in clients and send the message to each of them:

```
for (ClientHandler ch : clients){
    ch.sendMessage(message); //Or something
}
```

Comment: I did that bro. Same Problem only the clint which sends the msg will receive the Server's broadcast message. :(

Comment: But every client that is meant to receive the message is successfully accepted and added to the clients list?

Comment: Every client is accepted(Server Printed "New client accepted") for every client i connected. I don't know about what "added to client list" means

Comment: Well that every ClientHandler is in clients. You could also try adding a debug line in the ClientHandler that prints a message every time the send() method is called. You can figure out if it is actually trying to send it

Comment: Yup I tried that too. To my astonishment the debug line was printed 3 times(because i connected 3 clients) but the client got the server message only once(I expected client also to get message 3 times).

Comment: Im not quite understanding what your scenario is there. You have one server listening with one ServerSocket bound to an address and its successfully accepting clients. The clients are connecting to the server and are all assigned a Socket on the serverside, right?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your ClientHandler on pastebin or something? Maybe the error is hinding in there...

Comment: Clienthandler is there in the code i provided. Is there some thing wrong with that Clienthandler?

Comment: Ok, missed that ;). Can't really spot the error in there but there are some things you could do just to clean up the code a bit.
I would move the broadcast() method to the MultiThreadedServer, it just makes more sense to have it there and not in the clients. Also the receiving method looks a bit weird, there are great examples of socket handling here on stackoverflow, you could look at a few, maybe you spot the error yourself ;)